# Поддержка нескольких языков на странице

Tags: java, maven, jsf, locale, resourcebundle

Мне необходимо обеспечить на странице поддержку двух языков (англ, русс).

Как я понял, мне нужно в Resource Bundle создать translate.properties, translate_en.properties, translate_ru.properties.

Далее я записываю в них files = files и files = файлы

Теперь. Как мне воспользоваться этим, чтобы обеспечить два языка? Мне нужно создать кнопку смены языка на сайте, я так понимаю, и принимать от неё значение ключа (какой язык отображать), и как то связать это всё вместе с разметкой.

```
<p:layou>
    <p:layoutUnit>
        <h3>files</h3>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Что-то ещё нужно прописать в классе, я так подозреваю. Помогите понять всю цепь действий, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действия для включения поддержки многоязычности в JSF:

1. Создать сессионный компонент, содержащий сведения о текущем языке, и имеющий функции смены языка.

   ```
   @ManagedBean
   @SessionScoped
   public class LocaleController {

   public static Locale LOCALE_RU = new Locale("ru");
   public static Locale LOCALE_EN = new Locale("en");
   private Locale locale = LOCALE_RU;

   public Locale getLocale() {
       return locale;
   }

   public String selectLanguage(String selectedLanguage) {
       locale = convert(selectedLanguage);
       FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
       return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";//перезагружаем страницу
   }

   public static Locale convert(String languageName) {
       if ("en".equals(languageName)) {
           return LOCALE_EN;
       }

       return LOCALE_RU;
   }

   public boolean isRu() {
       return LOCALE_RU.equals(locale);
   }

   }
   ```
2. Указать язык на странице: `<f:view locale="#{localeController.locale}">`
3. Сообщить о поддерживаемых языках и ваших файлах с языковыми ресурсами в `faces-config.xml`. Заголовок и пространства имён указывают на версию спецификации JSF 2.2, если у Вас другая версия, то заголовок будет другим.

   ```
   <faces-config version="2.2"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
   <application>
       <locale-config>
           <default-locale>ru</default-locale>
           <supported-locale>ru</supported-locale>
           <supported-locale>en</supported-locale>
       </locale-config>
       <resource-bundle>
           <!--bundles - это имя папки с файлами ресурсов -->
           <base-name>bundles/translate</base-name>
           <var>translate</var>
       </resource-bundle>
   </application>
   </faces-config>
   ```
4. Добавить кнопки смены языка

   ```
   <p:commandLink value="English" action="#{localeController.selectLanguage('en')}" rendered="#{localeController.ru}"/>
   <p:commandLink value="Русский" action="#{localeController.selectLanguage('ru')}" rendered="#{not localeController.ru}"/>
   ```
5. Наполнить файлы с языковыми ресурсами. В `translate_en.properties` добавляем `files=files`, в `translate_ru.properties` добавляем `files=файлы`
6. Правильно использовать языковые ресурсы на странице

   ```
   <h3>#{translate.files}</h3>
   ```

   где `#{translate` ссылается на `var` из `faces-config.xml`

Comment: Я поправил свой ответ, там должно быть FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId(). org.omnifaces.util.Faces - это класс из библиотеки Omnifaces (http://showcase.omnifaces.org/), которая содержит ряд утилит, упрощающих жизнь при разработке JSF-приложений.

Comment: `javax.servlet.ServletException: /views/home.xhtml @16,113 rendered="#{LocaleController.ru}": Property 'ru' not found on type com.common.LocaleController`
Вылетает такая штука. Где у нас в LocaleController находится "ru" или что это значит?

Comment: Добавил метод isRu(). Проверьте у себя, в выражении {LocaleController.ru} первый символ (L) в нижнем регистре должен быть.

Comment: С Вашего позволения, последний вопросик, более частный:
`Can't find bundle for base name resources/translate, locale ru`
Как Вы прокоментировали:

`<!--bundles - это имя папки с файлами ресурсов -->
        <base-name>bundles/translate</base-name>`
У меня располагаются они в папке resources -- Resource Bundle 'translate', в которой все translate.properties.
Но почему то, по указанному пути, программа их не находит..

Comment: Проверьте, где фактически в собранном приложении находятся файлы. Для <base-name>bundles/translate</base-name> это должно быть my.war\WEB-INF\classes\bundles\translate_ru.properties