# Поддержка нескольких языков

Tags: java

Нужно создать объект(Возможно даже для каждого языка отдельный класс) который хранит в себе все сообщения. При нужде выводить пользователю сообщение в зависимости от его выбранного в настройках языка.

Мое приложение собирается поддерживать 3 языка: English Russian и Ukraine.

Решил их изобразить так.

```
public enum Language {
RUSSIAN(1), ENGLISH(2), UKRAINE(3);

private Integer id;

Language(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public static Language reLang(Integer id) {
    switch (id) {
        case 1:
            return RUSSIAN;
        case 2:
            return ENGLISH;
        case 3:
            return UKRAINE;
        default:
            return RUSSIAN;
    }
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

Выбранный язык пользователя я храню в виде числового идентификатора: 
Русский - 1
Английский - 2
Украинский - 3

Пример как я получаю язык пользователя.

```
User user = new User("UserName");
user.getLang(); // Получаю язык пользователя(enum). (Язык берется из базы данных Mysql).
```

Следующий этап который я прохожу это вывод сообщения пользователю.
Здесь у меня возникли проблемы т.к раньше я никогда такого еще не делал (Да и реализация у меня не лучшего типа).

Я создал класс под

```
public class UtilChat {

    public static void message(Language lang, User user, Messages messages){
//Знаю можно было получать язык юзера здесь. а не в методе его вводить 
//отдельно
    }
}
```

Этим статистическим методом я собираюсь выводить пользователю сообщение на выбранном им языке.
Тут у меня возник вопрос.

Каким наилучшим способом я могу хранить каждого языка сообщения?

Был вариант под каждый язык создать свой класс но до меня так и не дошло как правильно брать нужные сообщения из класс (с учетом языка).

Может есть где нибудь уже похожая реализация?

Answer (score 1):

**Как сделать поддержку нескольких языков?**

Главное в разработке - это не изобретать велосипеды.

За поддержку языков в Java отвечает класс [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

[Что такой Locale?](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/locale.php)

[Еще про Locale](http://java2ee.ru/i18n/locale.html)

Подобный вопрос на ru.stackoverflow: [Поддержка нескольких языков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584023/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5)

Соответственно нужно в конфигах/properties описать поддерживаемые языки.

**Где хранить тексты приложения на разных языках?**

Для этого используются шаблоны.
Например [Apache Velocity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Velocity).

То есть на каждый язык создается набор файлов-шаблонов. И в зависимости от выставленного в текущий момент времени `Locale`, подтягиваются шаблоны с нужным языком.

**Зачем всё это нужно?**

Описанный подход позволяет отделить саму реализацию бизнес логики от языковой зависимости. И также позволяет легко и быстро подключать новые языки без изменения бизнес логики.

Comment: Где решение? Где представление? Ничего нет, одна вода.

Comment: Решение по ссылке в ответе на подобный вопрос. Представление в цирке. В ответе набор компонент для изучения вопроса.

Answer (score -2):

```
enum Lang {
    RUSSIAN(new String[]{
        "сообщение1",
        "сообщение2"
    }),
    ENGLISH(new String[]{
        "message1",
        "message2"
    });

    final String[] msg;

    private Lang(final String[] str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }
}
```

В каком-то главном классе, делаем свойство, которое будет меняться:

```
private static Lang type = Lang.RUSSIAN;
```

И метод, который будет возвращать сообщения:

```
public static String msg(final int key) {
    return type.msg[key];
}
```

Используем:

```
System.out.println(msg(0)); // сообщение1
```

Comment: По моему Вы пытаетесь изобрести велосипед на квадратных колесах. А оно поедет? :) А если сообщений будет несколько тысяч, насколько удобно будет их редактировать в этом Enum и работать безликими номерами сообщений через номер индексов в Array?

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev, вряд-ли у ТСА будет более 50 текстов, а то и меньше будет вовсе. Про тысячи, вы уж загнули